# C++ program with approximately 10000 classes

Tags: c++

We are considering a C++ design where a family of classes will be autogenerated from configuration files. The classes will be quite similar and have a common base class. Will the sheer number of classes (worst case ~ 10000) incur problems of some kind?

Comment: Hard to say. Maybe. Maybe not. What problems are you concerned about? Do you think your design is ideal?

Comment: If you have a design that has 10000 classes, you should consider a different design pattern. Without knowing more details, the first thing that comes to mind based on what you described is decorators.

Comment: How many classes can c++ really handle, is the complexity linear?

Comment: I cringe a bit myself from creating all these classes, so I guess it might the smell of something - but I am not entirely sure of what? Anyway before contemplating this further at all I wanted a sanity check of the feasibility, and from @Kaz answer it seems a bad/risky idea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. In C++ implementations, each class generates multiple external symbols. This can lead to problems. For instance, on some platforms, if you're putting these classes into a shared library, you may find that a symbol-related structure such as a "global offset table" will overflow.

Comment: Thanks - it was something along these lines I was vary of.

Comment: I ran into this problem on a MIPS platform. The problem was that the global offset table overflow was ... undiagnosed. So suddenly a call to function `Foo::Bar` was mysteriously jumping into `Xyzzy::Blurg`, via the corrupted GOT. I was in the role of "toolchain/OS distro guy" I hacked a custom linker script in which I implemented a link-time warning for an overflown GOT to cause the build to fail. The developers then had to deal with it somehow, like splitting up the classes into multiple libraries or whatever.

Comment: Couldn't this be mitigated by not exporting the symbols?

Answer (score 0):

I have seen some projects that hit this kind of scale and still work. While I agree that there is eventually going to be a limit to the number of classes, I don't think that 10,000 is going to break on a modern machine with a modern compiler.

That said, this seems like a great candidate for a dummy run--write a quick program to spit out a bunch of randomly generated class definitions similar to your intended goal, and put them into a single massive CPP file. Run the compiler and check for unexpected fireworks. Make an obj file and try to link it into something. Keep increasing the class count until it breaks.

By the way, I agree that this does not sound like a great design.

Answer (score 0):

This is especially a problem if the base class defines a large number of virtual methods. The amount of memory used for v-tables is given by

```
vTableMemory = countOfVirtualMembers*countOfClasses*sizeof(void*)
```

That is, every virtual function defined in the base class has a cost of 80 kByte that is added to the size of the executable. *This is already more than fits into the L1 cache of a Haswell-CPU*. Consequently, calls to the virtual functions use by your class hierarchy will be quite costly. Take five virtual functions, and you have already more data then fits into L2 cache. Take twenty virtual functions, and you start to exceed the size of the last level cache. The performance impact of this can be severe.